# Saving binary data to file in javascript

Tags: javascript, java

Currently I can send my server an URL to file, then server saves that file to byte array and stores it in database. On demand, user can save that file.

It works fine for csv files (i have tested only those for now).

I'm having problems saving image files (png and jpeg).

Java code on getting file and saving it to byte array:

```
   ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   InputStream inputStream = url.openStream(); //url of given file
   int n = 0;
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

   while (-1 != (n = inputStream.read(buffer))) {
       output.write(buffer, 0, n);
   }
```

Part of my controller that sends back file through response:

```
    response.setBufferSize(8192);
    response.getOutputStream().write(file); //file is byte array
```

Javascript code for saving binary data to file and executing download:

```
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([data], {type: type}); //type is correct type (image/png, text/csv ...)
    var fileNameToSaveAs = name + '.' + extension; //Name of a file and correct extension
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
```

IrfanView gives me decode error.

Comment: You could just compare the binary data and see where it changes. Are you sure you're not receiving the data as string?

Comment: Somehow I get larger file via server compared to manually downloading image from browser (299KB with manual save vs 538KB with server).